# tcsh variable weirdness

Tags: environment-variables, tcsh

What makes `tcsh` ignore chars after \fa?

```
% set funky = "`perl -e 'print pack q(c*), 9,247..255'`"
% echo "$funky" | od -x
0000000 f709 f9f8 fbfa fdfc fffe 000a
0000013
% set funky = "`perl -e 'print pack q(c*), 10,247..255'`"
% echo "$funky" | od -x
0000000 f8f7 faf9 000a
0000005
```

`csh` does not:

```
% set funky = "`perl -e 'print pack q(c*), 9,247..255'`"
% echo "$funky" | od -x
0000000 f709 f9f8 fbfa fdfc fffe 000a
0000013
% set funky = "`perl -e 'print pack q(c*), 10,247..255'`"
% echo "$funky" | od -x
0000000 f8f7 faf9 fcfb fefd 0aff
0000012

% tcsh --version
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,nd,color,filec
% dpkg -l csh
ii  csh               20110502-2.1u amd64         Shell with C-like syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Locale:

```
% setenv LANG C
% set funky = "`perl -e 'print pack q(c*), 10,247..255'`"
% echo "$funky" | od -x
0000000 f8f7 faf9 fcfb fefd 0aff
0000012
```